# Exponential and Logarithmic Functions - $\log_2(x^2-4x-28)= 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got $x= \frac{45}{x-4} $

I know its wrong. Can someone show me how to solve.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but if you show your work, we can help you see what you did that was wrong. Can you show what you wrote, so we can help you identify incorrect steps in your process? I think that it is **very important** to look at your work and identify how you went awry--how else can you learn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem: We need to solve for $x$ in the given equation
$$\log_2(x^2-4x-28)=2$$
Remember that if $\log_a(b)=y$, then $a^y=b$. In our equation, $a=2$, $b=x^2-4x-28$, and $y=2$. Therefore $x^2-4x-28=2^2=4$. This is easy to solve for.
$$x^2-4x-28=4$$
$$x^2-4x-32=0$$
Factor it
$$(x-8)(x+4)=0$$
$$\color{green}{\boxed{x=8, \ -4}}$$
Hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_2(x^2 - 4x - 28) = 2$$
$$\implies x^2 - 4x - 28 = 2^2 = 4$$
$$x^2 - 4x - 32 = 0$$
$$(x - 8)(x + 4) = 0$$
$$x = 8, \ -4$$

Comment: Why only $x=8$?

Comment: I think I misread the problem somehow.